# Cypress tests do not start automatically after updating the file

Tags: cypress

Does anybody have a solution for the Cypress bug regarding not running the test automatically when a file has been updated. As far as I can see the bug was reported 3 years ago for the Windows OS. I faced it now on my machine on which the problem did not arise before. I suppose it happened after editing my cypress.json. I added "watchForFileChanges": false to it. But despite deleting this setting I still am not able to run the tests automatically after updating. Adding the setting "watchForFileChanges": true does not fix the problem. I use Visual Studio Code as my IDE but it is not the reason because the same bug I have if using command window only.

Answer (score 1):

```
I did this recently on Windows and do not see the issue
```

1. create a blank project (literally nothing in it)
2. npm init -y
3. npm install --save-dev cypress
4. added below under scripts into package.json
 "scripts": {
    "cypress:open": "cypress open"
}
5. npm run cypress:open
6. run one of the *spec.js file under IntegrationTests\examples
7. Test ran successfully
Now
8. added a simple_spec.js
9. Added sample test case
save the file.
10. Click on file from Cypress server window.
Test will run
Next time when any changes done in the spec file. Test ran automatically.